# Flutter Firebase Messaging - Handle Notification Navigation For foreground and background clicks

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-navigation

In one of my app want notification handling based on id, whether it is foreground or background. I'm not able to manage it.

What i want is when i receive the push notification, user should be navigated to the respective screens. even if we are on any of the current screen or app is in background. I also have splash screen in between. So, how can i manage the navigation even if i have somethings to fetch from web api and then navigate to some other screen.

I am getting push notification every time whether app is in foreground or background mode. Also, any of the toasts are not shown when notifications are received as per my following code.

I have added following code for notification handling,

```
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: "Main Navigator");
  FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  BuildContext _context;

  setupFirebaseMessaging() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      await _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: false),
      );
    }

    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage called : ${message.toString()}");
        notiMessage = message;
        getLocalNotification(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        showToast("onLaunch Called : ${navigatorKey.currentState}", context);
        print("onLaunch called : ${message.toString()}");
        navigateToDetailScreen(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        showToast("onResume Called : ${navigatorKey.currentState}", context);
        print("onResume called : ${message.toString()}");
        navigateToDetailScreen(message);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    setupFirebaseMessaging();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _context = context;
        return MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Test',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: primaryColor,
          accentColor: primaryDarkColor,
          // visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: SplashScreen(),
      );

navigateToDetailScreen(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  if (message['data']['id'] ==1) {
  navigatorKey.currentState.pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  } else if (message['data']['id'] ==2) {
  // some async work
  navigatorKey.currentState.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailScreen()));
  } else if (message['data']['id'] ==3) {
  // some async work
  navigatorKey.currentState.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DataScreen()));
  } else {
  // some async work
  navigatorKey.currentState.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
  } 
}
```

Above code doesn't work for my case. I am not able to get navigated to my desired screen. Also, how to survive **SplashScreen** is your initialscreen when handling notification navigation with async calculation?

Can anyone suggest me a proper way to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I am able to get this work for onResume but onLaunch seems to ignore same code completely.